# std::void_t and nested non type members

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have the following code where I get unexpected result (second `static_assert` fails):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_bananas : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_bananas<T, std::void_t<typename T::config::num_items>>
    : std::true_type {};

struct Config{
    static constexpr int num_items=42;
};

struct Bananas{
    using config = Config;
};

static_assert(is_bananas<int>::value == false);
static_assert(is_bananas<Bananas>::value == true);
```

When I use `T::config` instead of `T::config::num_items` code works as expected.

If I use `decltype` around `num_items` then it works.

Am I correct to assume that `void_t` only works with types?

Is there a nicer way to do what I want?
If somebody is confused by this(and think: just throw a `decltype`) - I find `decltype` hard to read in real code when there are long names and deep nesting so if there is a nicer way to do this with `void_t` or any other template code I would like to know.

Comment: "Am I correct to assume that void_t only works with types?" - yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a nicer way to do what I want?

Nice and nicer are subjective.

By example, I find very nice your `decltype()` solution.

Anyway... a possible alternative is define a substitute for `std::void_t` that works with value types

Something as

```
template <auto...>
using value_void_t = void;
```

and write

```
template <typename T>
struct is_bananas<T, value_void_t<T::config::num_items>>
   : std::true_type {};
```